# Adding dynamic button with dynamic label?

Tags: android, button, dynamic, numbers, label

I'm making an Android Application in which I want to add the `button` with a dynamic `label`.
the flow of the `Activity` is as follows:-

- When the main `Activity` loads, it will ask the user "HOW MANY BUTTONS USER WANTS?"
  eg:- if user type 4
- A new activity will open with 4 `EditText(s)` in it, in which user will give the names of the `Buttons`
  eg:- play, pause, stop, rewind
- As the user gives the names, final `Activity` will open with four buttons with their names as PLAY, PAUSE, STOP, REWIND.

I am done with the 1st and 2nd part but facing a problem with the 3rd part.Any help?

**Code of 1st Activity:-**

```
package com.example.dynamicbutton;
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private Button button,button1;
    EditText et;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addnames);
            et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0)
                {
                    String theText = et.getText().toString();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NameActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("text_names", theText);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**Code of the 2nd activity :-**

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
        String m = extras.getString("text_label");
        int m1=Integer.parseInt(m);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dynamically_create_view_element);

        final LinearLayout lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearMain);

        // create the layout params that will be used to define how your
        // button will be displayed
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        //Create four 
        for(int j=1;j<=m1;j++) 
        {   
            // Create LinearLayout
            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            // Create Button
            final Button btn = new Button(this);
            // Give button an ID
            btn.setId(j+1);
            btn.setText("Add To Cart"+j );
            // set the layoutParams on the button
            btn.setLayoutParams(params);

            final int index = j;

            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Log.i("TAG", "index :" + index);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked Button Index :" + index, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

            //Add button to LinearLayout
            ll.addView(btn);
            //Add button to LinearLayout defined in XML
            lm.addView(ll);  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you facing with (c) part? Have you tried anything? Or do you just want someone to provide the code for you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the code for your final activity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FinalActivity extends Activity {


String caption[4]={"play","edit","undo","delete"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.YourLayout);

        final LinearLayout lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearMain); // linearMain //is your linearlayout in XML file

        // create the layout params that will be used to define how your
        // button will be displayed
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        //Create four 
        for(int j=0;j<=4;j++) 
        {   
            // Create LinearLayout
            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            // Create TextView
            Button btn= new Button(this);
            btn.setText(caption[j]+j+"    ");
            ll.addView(btn);

            // Create TextView
            TextView lbl= new TextView(this);
            price.setText(j+"     ");
            ll.addView(lbl);

            // Create Button
            final Button btn = new Button(this);
                // Give button an ID
                btn.setId(j+1);
                btn.setText("Add To Cart");
                // set the layoutParams on the button
                btn.setLayoutParams(params);

                final int index = j;
                // Set click listener for button
                btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Log.i("TAG", "index :" + index);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Clicked Button Index :" + index, 
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });

               //Add button to LinearLayout
                ll.addView(btn);
               //Add button to LinearLayout defined in XML
                lm.addView(ll);  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a typo. Correct it. The double quotes is not closed after `"edit"`

Comment: thanks mate for your suggestion , i will definately look into it .

Answer (score 0):

This is really easy.
just follow these steps:-

1. Create a `Layout` with only a Button as a child object.
2. Create another layout with only `EditText` as the child object.
3. Create a Third layout with no object in it. This will be your final layout in which you will show your Play, Pause, Stop, Rewind etc buttons. You can use `LinearLayout`.
4. Create your **MainActivity**, in which user will enter the number of buttons he want.
5. Now, in your Java code, in MainActivity, when the user enters the number of buttons he wants, migrate him to next activity passing the number in an Intent.
6. OnCreate of your **SecondActivity**, Use `LayoutInflater` class to inflate your EditText inside a For-Loop, to dynamically load that layout the number of times user has entered.
7. Save the captions of the buttons in an ArrayList and pass it to **ThirdActivity**.
8. OnCreate of your **ThirdActivity**, dynamically load the Button Layout using `LayoutInflater` and set their respective texts, from the `ArrayList`